# Facebook API seems to change the spent value

Tags: facebook, api

we use facebook api to download report for our accounts.
the problem is - we have a GMT +2 account which we download its data everyday on 11:30AM GMT 0.

when i check the data again after a few days i see it changes, from decimal number to integer , for example - when view by campaigns, i got 201.23, 199.33, 199.20 ... after a few days it went 200, 200, 200.

at the end, i'm showing a different result for my customer in my application.

why is this happening?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the stats with the timetamps adjusted to account for the ad account's timezone - if the account is GMT +2 (check with a call to `/act_<ACCOUNT ID HERE>`), make sure you're asking for stats for `00:00:00 +0200` to the same time the next day

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Didn't quite understand what do you mean by  (check with a call to /act_<ACCOUNT ID HERE>). Also I forgot to add that we download every day the report for yesterdays date.

Comment: When you call `https://graph.facebook.com/act_<ACCOUNT ID>`, part of the response is the account's timezone, which is necessary to retrieve the correct stats, see the notes at the end of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adstatistics/ for details